# Google API PHP: Uncaught Exception on createAuthURL()?

Tags: php, google-api-php-client

I've just downloaded the latest Google API PHP and I'm trying it out with a "log in with Google" script. The API is throwing this exception that is apparently uncaught:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Auth_Exception' with message
>   'No scopes specified' in
>   /home/rlcoachi/public_html/hidden/googlelogin/src/Google/Client.php:178
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/rlcoachi/public_html/hidden/googlelogin/src/Google/Client.php(237):
>   Google_Client->prepareScopes() #1
>   /home/rlcoachi/public_html/hidden/googlelogin/api.php(76):
>   Google_Client->createAuthUrl() #2 {main} thrown in
>   /home/rlcoachi/public_html/hidden/googlelogin/src/Google/Client.php on
>   line 178

Line 74-77 of my `api.php` script is:

```
else 
{
    //For Guest user, get google login url
    $authUrl = $gClient->createAuthUrl();
}
```

gClient being a Google_Client object that's been setup with id, secret, url, key

[Full script is available here](http://www.sanwebe.com/2012/11/login-with-google-api-php)

Answer (score 1):

Go to file named googlelogin/src/Google/Client.php

search

```
protected $scopes = array();
```

then fill the array with scopes like

```
protected $scopes = array("userinfo.email", "userinfo.profile");
```

if you want to get user emailId as well as profile details...

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$client->setScopes(array(
     'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login',
     'profile',
     'email',
     'openid',
));
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to add an explanation of how your code works and how it solves the OP's problem. Many SO posters are newbies and will not understand the code you have posted.